# function to convert nad27 datum to nad83

Tags: javascript, php

How can I take a `NAD27` decimal coordinate like `39.748303,-104.998634` and convert it to `NAD83` or `WGS84` with a programming function in PHP or JS?

I know it can be done with GIS programs, but I need a programming function ideally in PHP, but I could convert from any language.

Comment: Have you research the problem? Have you attempted anything on your own? No one is going to just write some code up for you for free without any effort on your part.

Comment: I've been trying to do this for days. I tried using proj4js and proj4php but they cannot do the correct transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend proj4js. Lightweighted projection library https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js,

Let me know if that helps.

```
    var NAD2NAD = function(x,y){
    var NAD27= "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"; 
    var NAD83= "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs";
    return proj4(NAD27,NAD83,[x,y]);
};
```

your input in NAD27 39.748303,-104.998634,

Proj4js returns in datum NAD83 [ -104.998634, 39.74619740515981 ],

From http://tagis.dep.wv.gov/convert/
Result is 39.748289809487346 -104.99917122555918

i made the assumption that ellps value unchanged without knowing what extact projection your data is in.

Comment: proj4js cannot transform nad27 datums to nad83 correctly

Comment: What is the incorrect result for your conversion. And can you share your projections info?

Comment: I have an issue going on the pro4js github: https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/212

Comment: You absolutely right about the issue that proj4js does not have a datum shift grid function included. I tried in gdal `cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +to +proj=latlong +datum= NAD83 -f %.12f` input:-110.045977 33.081801 result is  -110.046617714069    33.081859609059. And compares [ -110.045977, 33.079841471460625 ] when using the same parameters in OP's post.